# Does the linker prefer .so files over .a files?

Tags: linker, llvm, julia, ld

I'm building Julia using a local LLVM build which contains both libLLVM*.so files and corresponding libLLVM*.a files. This was built first with `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`, which is responsible for the presence of the libLLVM*.so files.

libjulia.so, the library used by the `julia` executable, **always linked to the libLLVM*.so** files, even when I rebuilt LLVM with `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`(the default config). `llvm-config --libs $LIB`'s output with and without `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` didn't vary much and nothing seem to hint at `llvm-config` issuing linking options that'd direct the linker to link either *.so files or *.a files.

Why is this the case ? Is it s default behaviour of the linker to use .so files even when .a files of the same name exist ? Or, is there a build configuration cache that Julia reuses ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, to fulfil the option `-lfoo`, `ld` will by default link `libfoo.so` in preference to `libfoo.a` if both
are found in the same search directory, and when it finds either one it
will look no further.

You can enforce linkage of static libraries only by passing `-static` to the linkage, 
but in that case static versions must be found for *all* libraries - including
default system libraries - not just those you explicitly mention.

To selectively link a static library `libfoo.a`, without specifying `-static`,
you can use the explicit form of the `-l` option: `-l:libfoo.a` rather than
`-lfoo`.

`llvm-config` will emit library options in the `-lfoo` form whether you build
static or shared libraries, since those options will work correctly for
either, but you need to understand when using them how the linker
behaves. If you don't tell it otherwise, it will link the shared rather
than the static library when it faces the choice.

**Later**

> Why does ld prefer to link shared libraries over static ones?

AFAIK, it is not on record why the developers of `ld` made this decision long
ago, but the reason is obvious: If dynamic linkage is the default then
executables, by default, will not physically include additional copies of code
that can be provided to all executables by a single shared copy, from a shared library. Thus
executables, by default, will economize their code size and the aggregate of
excecutables that constitutes your system or mine will be vastly smaller than
it would have to be without sharing. Shared libraries and dynamic linkage 
were invented so that systems need not be be bloated with duplicated code.

Dynamic linkage brings with it the complication that an executable
linked with shared libraries, when distributed to a system other than the
one on which it was built, does not carry its dynamic dependencies with it. It's
for that reason that all the approved mechanisms for installing a new binaries 
on systems - package managers - ensure that all of their dynamic dependencies
are installed as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why does `ld` prefer to link shared libraries over static ones ?

Comment: @kesari Updated answer